# Transfer of SVN Repos

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Using VisualSVN on a dedicated server and TortoiseSVN on user machines.  We will soon be getting a new server and I need to transfer repo's across.  What's the best way to do this?
Is it simpler to just setup VisualSVN again and Import code from scratch on user machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way with least possibility of anyone inexperienced getting their working copies chewed/broken/confused:

1. Make sure everyone commits their changes to the old repo.
2. Copy the whole repo folder entirely from the old machine to the new
   machine. Install and open VisualSVN on the new machine, and select 'Import
   Repository'.
3. Have everyone checkout their project from the new repo.

Comment: I copied across, imported and then using Tortoise on the clients simply chose relocate, pointed to the new server and worked great.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it simpler to just setup VisualSVN again and Import code from scratch on user machines?

Well, it's simpler, but only if you don't mind throwing away the entire history of your codebase. For most people, that isn't an option.

I haven't done a migration with VisualSVN Server, so I don't know if they have any built-in tools to make this easier. However, there is a [well-defined process for migrating your repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) to a new server which you should follow. If VisualSVN Server has a feature for migrating your data, it's almost certainly based upon what's documented in the official manual.

Once you've migrated your data, your users will need to run `svn relocate` to point their working copies at the new server.